# MySQL - Group by two Columns

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this

```
id, user_id   , type, date
3,  ivnWvOQqoN, iOS , 2015-11-24 15:46:09
4,  dskIbJhuSd, iOS , 2015-11-23 19:39:31
5,  dskIbJhuSd, iOS , 2015-11-24 23:37:45
6,  ----------, iOS , 2015-11-22 23:38:05
7,  ----------, iOS , 2015-11-23 23:38:10
```

And right now I am doing a query like this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS entries, user_id, DATE(created_at) as date, device_type
FROM App_Usage
WHERE device_type = 'iOS'
  AND created_at between 2015-11-22 AND 2015-11-25
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), user_id
```

This return results that I would expect it looks like this

```
((1L, '----------', datetime.date(2015, 11, 22), 'ios'),
(1L, 'dskIbJhuSd', datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), 'ios'),
(1L, '----------', datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), 'ios'),
(1L, 'dskIbJhuSd', datetime.date(2015, 11, 24), 'ios'),
(1L, 'ivnWvOQqoN', datetime.date(2015, 11, 24), 'ios')
```

The last two lines in the above code, become the last line in the next code. And the second line in above code becomes 2nd line in code below.

My question is could I group by date and if the user is not `'----------'`, so it would return a result like this

```
((1L, '----------', datetime.date(2015, 11, 22), 'ios'),
(1L, 'combo of users' datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), 'ios'),
(1L, '----------', datetime.date(2015, 11, 23), 'ios'),
(2L, 'combo of users', datetime.date(2015, 11, 24), 'ios'),
```

I left the user_id in the first results to show that as long as the user is `'---------'` I want those grouped and the others grouped.

So I want to group by date, and then by where user is not `'----------'`, how could I do this or is it even possible?

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

OUTPUT:

```
number of uses, user_id**, type, date;
(1, '----------', 'ios', '2015-11-22 23:38:05'),
(1, 'some users or combo', 'ios', '2015-11-22 13:33:33'),
(2, 'some users or combo', 'ios', '2015-11-23 13:35:37'),
(1, '----------', 'ios', '2015-11-24 00:09:44'),
(2, 'some users or combo', 'ios', '2015-11-24 00:09:44'),
```

**So I want any users that is '----------' to be 
grouped with '-------' but any user that is not '--------' to be 
goruped with all other users. As you can see on the 24rd, the 
2 different uses are put as one and the use that was '-------'
is serperate (this is the last two lines above)

Comment: Can you provide an sqlfiddle and proper result

Comment: @Strawberry sure give me a minute

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: @Strawberry working on fiddle, I added an edit to the result to try to make it more clear, I want the '----------' users grouped and then all other users grouped, if you see what I mean

Comment: @jarlh in this instance it doesn't matter

Comment: @spenf10 unfortunately you lost me at '1L'

Comment: @Strawberry, perhaps not. But I still think it's good practice to always write valid SQL.

Comment: @Strawberry see edit and here is fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418d6c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select count(*) as entries, dateCreate, device_type, user_id
from 
    (SELECT DATE(created_at) as dateCreate, device_type, case when user_id = '----------' then '-----------' else 'combo of users' as user_id  
    FROM App_Usage 
    WHERE device_type = 'iOS' 
    AND created_at between 2015-11-22 
    AND 2015-11-25) as temp_table 
GROUP BY dateCreate, user_id, device_type
```

note: used dateCreate instead of date as it is a keyword

Comment: this give error `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias `

Comment: change what to add alias?

Comment: this query removes any values where user_id = '----------' from the result is that correct?

Comment: Great. I added an edit to the result I want in the final code section of question to try to make it more clear, I want the '----------' users grouped and then all other users grouped, if you see what I mean

Comment: please see desired output in edit and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/418d6c this fiddle shows what is in the table

Comment: I get this error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''----------' then '-----------' else 'combo of users' as user_id  
    FROM App_' at line 3`

Comment: try `(case when user_id = '----------' then '-----------' else 'combo of users' end) as user_id`

Comment: AMAZING, last question is this bad from as the people in the question comments where saying or is this completely fine to do? Thank you

Comment: It is always good practice to include all column references in select to GROUP BY. You can now accept it as answer and uproot. Regards.